# Flutter Keyboard that Appear and Disappear

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a problem with My Flutter Project...

The Keyboar always **Appear** and Suddenly **Disappear** when I try to click the TextField..

But It's only happen in this Page...

here is the **Code**

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:chat_chat_8/service/auth.dart';
import 'package:chat_chat_8/theme/style.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

class ProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ProfilePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ProfilePage> createState() => _ProfilePageState();
}

class _ProfilePageState extends State<ProfilePage> {
  TextEditingController txt_name = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController txt_status = new TextEditingController();

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  ImagePicker picker = ImagePicker();

  var stateCondition;
  var profileImage;
  File? uriImage;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget PhotoProfile(String userImage) {
      if (profileImage == null) {
        profileImage = userImage;
      }
      return Container(
          height: 197.53,
          width: 197.53,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: profileImage == userImage
                  ? NetworkImage(profileImage.toString())
                  : FileImage(uriImage as File) as ImageProvider,
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(150),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 2,
              color: Purple_sub,
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              Container(
                height: 42.18,
                width: 42.18,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      XFile? image =
                          await picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                      if (image != null) {
                        setState(() {
                          profileImage = File(image.path).toString();
                          uriImage = File(image.path);
                        });
                      }
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Purple_sub,
                      shadowColor: Colors.black54,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Icon(
                          Icons.mode_edit_outline_outlined,
                          color: Colors.white,
                          size: 25,
                        ),
                      ],
                    )),
              )
            ],
          ));
    }

    Widget ConditionComboBox(var userCondition) {
      if (stateCondition == null) {
        stateCondition = userCondition;
      }

      return Container(
        height: 55,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          border: Border.all(
            color: Text_Field,
          ),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(13),
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton<String>(
              focusColor: Colors.white,
              value: stateCondition,
              //elevation: 5,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Color(0xff595555),
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
              //iconEnabledColor: Colors.black,
              items: <String>[
                'Available',
                'Unavailable',
                'Busy',
              ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: Text(
                    value,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Color(0xff595555),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }).toList(),
              hint: Text(
                "Select your condition",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Color(0xff595555),
                    fontSize: 14,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
              ),
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  stateCondition = value;
                });
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    Widget TextProfile(String userName, String userStatus) {
      txt_name.text = userName;
      txt_status.text = userStatus;

      return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 56.67,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: txt_name,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Color(0xff595555),
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Text_Field),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Purple_sub,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 18.19,
          ),
          Container(
            height: 56.67,
            child: TextFormField(
              controller: txt_status,
              style: TextStyle(
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Color(0xff595555),
                fontSize: 24,
              ),
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Text_Field),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Purple_sub,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }

    Widget SaveButton() {
      return Container(
        height: 50,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            AuthMethod().updateUser(
              _auth.currentUser!.uid,
              txt_name.text,
              uriImage != null ? uriImage as File : null,
              txt_status.text,
              stateCondition,
            );
          },
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Purple_sub,
          ),
          child: Text(
            'Complete',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Padding(
          padding: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets,
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 51.32),
            margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal: 22.55,
            ),
            child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("Users")
                  .doc(_auth.currentUser!.uid)
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Container();
                }
                return Container(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Image.asset(
                            'assets/images/logo_app.png',
                            height: 50,
                            width: 50.64,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 11.25,
                          ),
                          Text(
                            'Profile',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              color: Colors.black,
                              fontSize: 27,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 44,
                      ),
                      PhotoProfile(
                        snapshot.data.data()["userImage"],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 54.83,
                      ),
                      TextProfile(
                        snapshot.data.data()["userName"],
                        snapshot.data.data()["userStatus"],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 18.19,
                      ),
                      ConditionComboBox(
                        snapshot.data.data()["userCondition"],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 100.98,
                      ),
                      SaveButton(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 65.79,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I've tries many ways to solve this matter such as like in google
but no works at all

And my senior also can not solve this problem

I hope Some body can help me to Solve this Problem

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to get all of the widgets (except the scaffold) out of the build method.